# jquery multiple object selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

well we can select multiple group of elements like:

```
$('#id1, #id2, .class1, .class2')
```

in my jquery plugin i have created some elements:

```
var shadowed = $('<div>').//stuff here
var container = $('<div>').//stuff here
```

now I want to select both of these elements and apply some css but

```
$(shadowed, container).css({stuff here});
```

doesn't work. should I repeat everything for both of them?

```
$(shadowed).css({stuff here});
$(container).css({stuff here});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$(shadowed).add(container).css({...});
```

Or rather, since they're already jquery objects,

```
shadowed.add(container).css({...});
```

Comment: noooo, ignore the names, as they all are position absolute i'm just trying to set, height,width, line-height,... as the most inner element so they don't be zero-width

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question then. If you have a jquery object called `shadowed` and one called `container`, doing `shadowed.add(container)` will return a new object with all the elements from both original objects. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I want to give the same css for both of these jquery elements

Comment: right. when I saw add, I thought its something like .append() and I thought that the name container has caused misunderstanding. Thanks a lot